# Using VBA to switch between active worksheets only

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that changes between active worksheets only after a prescribed amount of time.

I have several hidden sheets, and currently, this code will cycle me to the last visible sheet, and then pause on that sheet for the same amount of time that it would take to cycle through the hidden sheets as well. So I end up looking at my last visible sheet for several times longer than the other sheets.

This is my code.

```
Public Sub Switch()
 Dim ws As Worksheet

Do
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        DoEvents
    Next ws
Loop


End Sub
```

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 3):

Use the worksheet's `Visible` property:

```
Public Sub Switch()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Do
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                'Only process things if the sheet is visible
                ws.Activate
                Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")
                DoEvents
            End If
        Next ws
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the `DoEvents` for?

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much.

Comment: @BruceWayne - Not sure why the OP had it there, but I didn't bother to remove it

Comment: ...@YowE3K - makes sense to me! Normally, isn't `DoEvents` used to allow Excel to do other things while waiting on a loop? As far as I can recall, I've only used it when doing things like loading a URL via an IE Object.

Comment: @BruceWayne - yes, `DoEvents` hands control back to the operating system (or to Excel which then passes back to the o/s?) so that other processes can be run.  Unfortunately I have never really worked out when it is and isn't required in normal code - and I find some code refuses to allow Ctrl-Break without it, and other code does (which means I have on many occasions had to "terminate" Excel because of a bad bit of code).  My best guess is it depends on whether the macro is chewing up all the CPUs or whether it is just using a single one.